# Why is this python library causing an error in my sql query?

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, textblob

I am trying to run a sql query on some data I generated in databricks, but I am getting an error when running the SQL query that is referencing a library I used for the sentiment analysis.

This is the query `%sql select sentiment, count(*) as Demo from tweets_parsed group by sentiment`

This is the block of code prior using the python library

```
def get_sentiment(text):
    from textblob import TextBlob
    tweet = TextBlob(text)
    if tweet.sentiment.polarity < 0:
      sentiment = "negative"
    elif tweet.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        sentiment = "neutral"
    else:
        sentiment = "positive"
    return sentiment
  
# Define your function
getSentiment = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: get_sentiment(x), StringType())

# Apply the UDF using withColumn
tweets = tweets.withColumn('sentiment', getSentiment(col("tweet")))
```

And this is the error I get when trying to run the SQL query

```
Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 3761.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 3761.0 (TID 5402, 10.81.233.238, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 460, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 150, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 449, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: g(f(*a))
  File "<command-3730768793397314>", line 13, in <lambda>
  File "<command-3730768793397314>", line 2, in get_sentiment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
```

the textblob library is installed and working just when I run this query is when I get an error referencing that library.

Does anyone know what may be the issue?

Comment: the environment which runs the sql query probably hasn't access to the installation directory of textblob. Would be useful to know how you run your code.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'` That error message says that the textblob module isn't installed.  How did you install it, and what directory was it installed into?

Comment: @JohnGordon I install textblob via `%sh pip install textblob` and then import on the cell under it. The python block that uses text blob works its just this query.

Comment: @IjonTichy I run all cells above it first and the cell that installs and imports textblob, along with the cell that uses textblob, works it is just this query. this is the directory in databricks that textblob is being installed when running `%sh pip install textblob`             /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages